Magnolia CMS edit toolbar missing after updating DNS and domain name
I recently had to update my website’s DNS and domain name due to DNS expiration. After updating the servername in Apache configuration with the new domain and URL, I logged into Magnolia CMS to edit pages. However, the edit toolbar is no longer visible on the page, and only the static content is displayed.
The website itself is loading fine with the new domain, but I can't access the Magnolia editing tools. Has anyone encountered this issue or knows what might be causing the toolbar to not appear after a DNS or domain name change?
Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated!
Updated the Apache configuration to reflect the new domain and URL after the DNS expired. Cleared the Magnolia cache and restarted the server to ensure the changes took effect.
I expected the Magnolia CMS edit toolbar to appear when logged in, allowing me to edit pages like before but it didn't. I'm using Magnolia Community Edition, 4.5.11.

4.5.x is very very old. You should consider upgrade, or since current is 6.3 and there were so many changes in between, probably complete rewrite.
As for the issue you are facing, it's most likely that the script generating the bars is just cached with the old domain name. Try different browser and make sure to flush the browser and server cache.

Hi Jan,
Thanks for your response! I did clear the server cache, but the edit toolbar is still not appearing. However, I noticed that when I access the site via localhost with port forwarding, the edit toolbar does show up.

Hmm. Strange. Did you flush the browser cache as well? It's really old version so I don't recall all the quirks it might have had. Maybe also check in config whether the  /server/defaultBaseUrl value matches your new domain, tho I don't think it would have any influence.
